# Problem with two concurrent workers accessing mysql with tornado

Tags: python, mysql, python-multiprocessing, tornado, threadpoolexecutor

I have this simple program composed by two workers: Worker1 inserts records that Workers2 should read. The problem is that during execution Workers2 reads 0 records. Launched separately from CLI they work correctly. The "culprit" seems to be tornado. Any idea?

```
import time
import munch
from tornado import concurrent
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import logging
import pymysql

config = munch.munchify({"mysql_host": "127.0.0.1", "mysql_port": 3306, "mysql_user": "", "mysql_password": "", "mysql_db": ""})

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)

class Worker1():
    CONST_TYPE_ID = 'worker1'

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host=config.mysql_host, port=config.mysql_port, user=config.mysql_user,
                                    passwd=config.mysql_password, db=config.mysql_db, charset='UTF8MB4',
                                    local_infile=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    def single_run(self):
        print("Single run of worker:", self.CONST_TYPE_ID)
        query = "insert into readwrite (timestamp) values (now())"
        self.conn.ping(True)
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        self.conn.commit()

class Worker2():
    CONST_TYPE_ID = 'worker2'

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host=config.mysql_host, port=config.mysql_port, user=config.mysql_user,
                                    passwd=config.mysql_password, db=config.mysql_db, charset='UTF8MB4',
                                    local_infile=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    def single_run(self):
        print("Single run of worker:", self.CONST_TYPE_ID)
        query = "select * from readwrite"
        self.conn.ping(True)
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        for row in self.cursor.fetchall():
            print(row)

def run_worker(worker):
    i = 0
    instance = worker()
    while True:
        try:
            i += 1
            print("Starting {name} - run {iter}".format(name=instance.CONST_TYPE_ID, iter=i))
            instance.single_run()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception('Worker {} got error {!r}, errno is {}'.format(instance.CONST_TYPE_ID, e, e.args[0]))
        print("Waiting...")
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    workers = [Worker1, Worker2]
    executor.map(run_worker, workers)
    IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding self.conn.commit() after self.cursor.execute(query) in Worker2.